# Image analysis technique to determine approximate change in view over a short period of time?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, robotics, opticalflow

I am working on an open source package for robot owners.  I want to do a decent job of detecting when the robot is having movement problems.  One of the problems the robot commonly has is that the back wheel gets "tucked underneath" in a bad way and makes it turn very slowly when on carpet.  I believe that with a combination of accelerometer value inspection and (I hope) a relatively simple yet robust vision analysis technique, I will be able to tell when the robot is having this specific problem.

What I need is to be able to analyze two images, separated by about 1/2 second in time, and get a numerical value that tells about how close they are, but in a way that has some intelligence about the objects in the screen instead of just a simple color/hue/etc. analysis.  I've heard of an algorithm called optical flow that is used in object and scene tracking, but I'm hoping I don't need something heavyweight.

Is there an machine vision algorithm/function that can analyze two JPEG's and tell if they belong to the same scene and viewpoint, yet can also deliver a numerical monotonically increasing value that tells me rough how different they are?  If I could get that numerical value and compare it to the number of milliseconds past, while examining the current accelerometer activity, I believe I can detect when the robot is having the "slow turn of death" problem.

If so, please tell me the basic technique involved, and if you know of machine vision library that implements it, which one it is.

Comment: Why do you need vision to solve this problem? Did you do some tests with the accelerometer to see if the acceleration values have a specific form when you are in the "tucked underneath" situation? Or maybe integrated the acceleration once to get velocity and observed it? I bet you could detect sudden drops in speed and act on that.

Comment: I wanted to suggest optical flow but then I saw, that you already know about it. Another way could be to find some keypoints and match only those between the two images. I have no experience with this, however, so I am not sure if it is computationally less expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but in a way that has some intelligence about the objects in the screen instead of just a simple color/hue/etc. analysis

What you are suggesting is a complex problem by itself, so forget about 'lightweight' solutions. Probably you are going to need something like optical flow.

Other options I would recommend you looking into are:

- Vanishing points detection and variation from image to image. This quite fits into your problem domain [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point#Detection_of_vanishing_points)
- Disparity map: related to optical flow. Used for stereographic vision, but I think you can use it for the kind of application you are looking for. Take a look at [this](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/disparity-maps/)